# How to give administrator rights to the local user Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, user-profiles

Is there way to give local user rwx rights on Windows 10 Pro 20h1?I need to make user possible to execute only 1 file in user directory

Comment: Is this a personal computer or is it on a domain?

Comment: personal computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use a utility such as
[RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html)
with which you may call a program that requires a password, but while keeping the
password itself completely secret.

You may run an application as another user or even start program as administrator
from a limited account, just the same as using the command
[runas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)),
but without manually entering the password on each run.

The password and all other details are kept by RunAsSpc in an encrypted database,
so the administrator's password is not visible to the user running the command.

For more details about using it see the article
[Pass the password to Runas with RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/guidance.html).
RunAsSpc is free for private use.

Comment: _runas_ is what i was finding for, Thanks!